# Mark a resource non-critical in a Pacemaker cluster

Tags: pacemaker

Is there a way to set a resource as non-critical in a OpenAIS/Pacemaker cluster?
e.g.

- 2 node cluster
- 1 resource group with 4 resource (A, B, C and D)

If resource A, B or C fails, the cluster should restart/relocate resources as usual. If resource D fails cluster should only trying to restart it (for example with max 5 attempts then stop) without relocate the resource group.
How I can set the resource D as "non-critical"?

Tks

Comment: the only way i found to archive something like this, was primitive dummy ocf:pacemaker:Dummy \
 op monitor interval="10s" timeout="60s" on-fail="ignore" \
 meta migration-threshold="infinity" target-role="Started"
like that, the non important resource has a fail-count=1000000

Answer (score 1):

the only way i found to archive something like this, was

```
 primitive dummy ocf:pacemaker:Dummy \ 
 op monitor interval="10s" timeout="60s" on-fail="ignore" \ 
 meta migration-threshold="infinity" target-role="Started"
```

like that, the non important resource has a fail-count=1000000